# How can I prevent SDKs collecting ANDROID_ID?

Tags: android, sdk, hook, reverse-engineering, privacy-policy

I have to help some Android app to do privacy compliance. The app contains many SDKs that collect ANDROID_ID which violate the regulatory. These SDKs are needed and typically have no sources. How can I prevent them collecting ANDROID_ID? Any workaround is OK because the time is short.